# API to download/upload public keys to pgp universal server

Tags: pgp, openpgp

Hi we developed a secure pgp application. We are able to create pgp keys and upload it to public openpgp keyservers and also we are able to retrive keys from openpgp servers. but the issue is we are unable to retrive public keys of recipients from symantec universal pgp servers.  Is there any way/api to download and upload public keys from/to universal pgp server?Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for keys in Symantec PGP Universal Server with enabled LDAP.

Commercial .NET API is available [here](http://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/examples/ldap-openpgp-key-servers/#search)
Commercial Java API is available [here](https://www.didisoft.com/java-openpgp/examples/exchange-keys-with-pgp-ldap-servers/)

In order for you to be able upload keys the SEMS server must be configured with an LDAP account with write access.